# Can two stateless EJB's share the same request scoped entity manager?

Tags: ejb, entitymanager, requestscope

I've decided to use a request scoped container managed `EntityManager` and I've created a producer for that reason:

```
@RequestScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

I've got two EJB's that expose a remote client view:

```
@Remote
public interface EJB1 {
    void createPerson(int id, String firstName, String lastName);
}

@Remote
public interface EJB2 {
    void containsEntity(Person person);
}

@Stateless
public class EJB1Impl implements EJB1 {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @EJB
    private EJB2 ejb2;

    @Override
    public void createPerson(final int id, final String firstName, final String lastName) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(id);
        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        entityManager.persist(person);
        System.out.println("EJB1Impl: persistence context contains entity: " + entityManager.contains(person));
        ejb2.containsEntity(person);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class EJB2Impl implements EJB2 {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void containsEntity(final Person person) {
        System.out.println("EJB2Impl: PersistenceContext contains entity: " + entityManager.contains(entity));
        person.setLastName("new name");
        //entityManager.merge(person);
    }
}
```

The EJB's are deployed on WildFly 10. I access them by a remote client using [this tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI?_sscc=t). The current version throws this exception: `org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`. If I remove the `@RequestScoped` annotation from the producer, I don't get an exception but the `EntityManager` injected into the second `EJB` returns `false` when asked if it contains the entity and if I want the changes made to the entity (the change of the last name) to have any effect, I have to call `entityManager.merge(person)`, which apparently means that the entity is detached. I'm sure that the second `EJB` executes withing the same transaction because if I inject an `EJBContext` and call `setRollbackOnly()` the transaction started in `EJB1` is rolled back and a new person is not inserted into the data base.

The documentation of `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` says that the request scope is active during any remote method invocation of any `EJB`, so what gives? How can I share an `EntityManager` during a request across multiple `EJB's`